# Is there a way to split a list like this?

Tags: python, list, split, tuples

I have a list `[1,0,2,6,8]` and I want to split it as this`[(1,0),(0,2),(2,6),(6,8)]` where each element of the result is a tuple, how can I write my code?

Answer (score 1):

If you use python 3.10, you can use `pairwise` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import pairwise
pairwise([1, 0, 2, 6, 8])
```

If you want the result as a list instead of iterator, surround `pairwise` with `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` we can try:

```py
inp = [1, 0, 2, 6, 8]
print(list(zip(inp[0:4], inp[1:5])))  # [(1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[1,0,2,6,8]
zip(x, x[1:])
```

Should do it.If python 3 you can make a list out of it before tring as it returns iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Using zip and slicing we can try
s = [1,0,2,6,8]

print(list(zip(s[:-1],s[1:])))

Comment: No need to slice the first list. `list(zip(s, s[1:]))` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The third-party [Toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library has a function [`sliding_window`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.sliding_window) to do this, as well as lots of other useful functions:

```
>>> from toolz.itertoolz import sliding_window
>>> list(sliding_window(2, [1,0,2,6,8]))
[(1, 0), (0, 2), (2, 6), (6, 8)]
```

Note that the functions in Toolz generally return lazy sequences (in the same way that `range` and `zip` do, for example), so I've called `list` explicitly to consume that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without using zip, which may result more friendly if you're starting to code:

```
x = [1,0,2,6,8]
[(x[i], x[i+1]) for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

But zip is the way to go in general if you want, well... to zip items.